# Инициализация ссылочной переменной класса в конструкторе

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14

Допустим есть такой код, который ничего не делает

```
class B{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void func() override
    {

    };

};

class A
{
public:
    A(B& d) :b(d)
    {

    }
private:
    B &b;
};

A func()
{
    D d = D();
    return A(d);
}

int main()
{
    A a = func();//тут уже в а.b будет хранится мусор
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как провести инициализацию ссылки на базовый класс в конструкторе, чтобы после не возвращался мусор?

Comment: D d = D(); - локальная переменная, разве нет? и передаётся по ссылке.

Comment: да в этом и дело. она разрушается при выходе из func(), поэтому и храниться мусор. Вот как провести инициализацию в конструкторе чтобы в объекте хранилась копия того, что приходит по ссылке.

Comment: а зачем так сложно? Почему бы не хранить там указатель например?

Comment: Я обычно писал на java, где подобная организация через ссылки не вызывает никаких вопросов. Решил и тут сделать также, но возникли проблемы. А как вы предлагаете решить этот вопрос через указатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `d` в функции `func` - это локальная переменная функции, которая прекратит свое существование после выхода из функции.

```
A func()
{
    D d = D();
    return A(d);
}
```

Поэтому ссылка на эту переменную вне функции будет недействительна.

Лучше сделать член данных  класса `A` в виде указателя вместо ссылки. Например,

```
class A
{
public:
    A( B *b ) :b(b)
    {

    }
private:
    B *b;
};


A func()
{
    D *d = new D();
    return A(d);
}
```

Если же все же хотите передавать ссылку, то эта ссылка должна так же быть параметром функции. Например

```
A func( D &d )
{
    return A(d);
}
```

Comment: да я понимаю в чем проблема, но хотелось обойтись в этом месте без использования new. Есть такая возможность?

Comment: @Kushner Как я уже написал, вы можете передавать ссылку на объект функции в качестве аргумента. То есть объект должен быть создан в том месте, откуда вызывается функция.

Comment: А в с++ есть возможность передачи производного объекта в конструктор класса как ссылку на базовый класс, а там уже произвести копирование и присвоение внутренней переменной класс?

Comment: @Kushner Да, конечно.

Comment: А как, чтобы это было корректно? ну то есть какие изменения провести в конструкторе A(), чтобы это отработало

Comment: @Kushner Лучше закройте этот вопрос, так как на него вы получили ответ, и откройте новый. Это плохо, когда комментарии заменяют собой вопрос и ответ.

Comment: создал другой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585619/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81

Comment: @kushner: Если ответ решает вашу проблему, поставьте ему зелёную галочку (слева).