# Копирование в конструкторе класса того, на что указывает ссылка на базовый класс

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14

Допустим есть такой код, который ничего не делает

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    void func() override
    {

    };

};

class A
{
public:
    A(B& d) :b(d)
    {

    }
private:
    B &b;
};

A func()
{
    D d = D();
    return A(d);
}

int main()
{
    A a = func();//тут уже в а.b будет хранится мусор
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как провести инициализацию ссылки на базовый класс в конструкторе, чтобы после не возвращался мусор? Я понимаю что проблема в том, что локальный объект уничтожается по завершению функции. Можно исправить это вот так:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( B *b ) :b(b)
    {

    }
private:
    B *b;
};


A func()
{
    D *d = new D();
    return A(d);
}
```

Но мне бы хотелось бы не использовать динамическое выделение памяти, а передать в конструктор все-таки ссылку на базовый класс. Там уже произвести копирование того, на что указывает ссылка и присвоить это полю класса A.

Заранее благодарю всех за полученные ответы/замечания.

Comment: Думаю, что проблема заключается в неправильном дизайне классов. Вследствии этого возникают вопросы. . Наверное вам следует пересмотреть дизайн классов.

Comment: Копируйте на здоровье то "на что указывает ссылка". Но помните, что управление временем жизни этой копии - это ваша задача. А уж где и как вы собрались создавать эту копию - это вопрос, на который в таком абстрактно-искусственном контексте конкретного ответа нет.

Answer (score 0):

> Но мне бы хотелось бы не использовать динамическое выделение памяти, а передать в конструктор все-таки ссылку на базовый класс.

Реализация ваших пожеланий в данной трактовке - невозможна. В комментариях @Vlad from Moscow вам ответил правильно, нужно пересмотреть дизайн. Причина простая, и вы сами ее озвучили, время жизни объекта класса, созданного на стеке, ограничено областью объявления.

Выхода видится три:

- попробуйте объект, созданный на стеке, заставить отработать полностью, до его уничтожения, пусть там сделает свою работу
- создавайте объект на хипе, возможно оберните его в shared_ptr|unique_ptr, и используйте его по назначению вне области объявления
- пересмотрите архитектуру создания/взаимодействия объектов, возможно имеет смысл задействовать паттерны проектирования "фабрика", "посетитель", etc...

Comment: А нет варианта скопировать содержимое того, что хранится по ссылке и присвоить ссылке на базовый класс, которая хранится как поле класса?

Comment: Это первый вариант, который я указал

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @kushner, раз вы хотите работать со ссылками, то ссылки должны ссылаться на "живые" объекты класса. В вашем случае, если не хотите на хипе строить, объявляйте все нужные переменные в main, и ими манипулируйте. Но, имхо, объявлять виртуальную функцию и не использовать указатели - это немного странный подход. Напишите, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Я надеялся передать объект с помощью ссылки на базовый класс в конструктор. На основании его в конструкторе создать копию, а уже эту копию присвоить полю класса, которая является ссылкой. 
Если бы конструктор принимал бы не базовый класс, то создать его копию не составить труда, но тут ссылка на базовый. 
Наверное правильно спросить, можно ли создать копию объекта на который указывает ссылка на базовый класс(ну и конечно копия должна сохранить тип)?

Comment: У вас небольшая путаница в терминологии, из за этого и такой "дизайн". Не бывает ссылок на класс! Бывают ссылки на экземпляр класса. И "политика" использования ссылок иная. Ссылки используются, как правило, чтобы передавать параметры без создания копий. Пересмотрите еще раз свой дизайн. А лучше всего опишите не как вы делаете, а какой функционал хотите построить.